# Measurablity of monotone functions defined on an interval

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that a monotone function defined on an interval is continuous almost everywhere 
Then it is measurable except on a set of measure zero which is also measurable, then taking the union of the two sets ( the set of measures zero and the set where the function is continuous) will be also measurable ?

I proved the above like this but I'm not sure if my answer is right or not.

Comment: I think that in the word "monotone" is forgotten in the first line of the body.

Comment: Yes it was mistaken, sure It must be monotone to conclude that it is continuous almost everywhere

Answer (score 0):

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous a.e. then there exists a set of zero measure $M \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f|_{M^c}: M^c \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Now $f|_{M^c}^{-1} U$ is open in $M^c$, meaning that we can write it as
$$
f|_{M^c}^{-1} U = V \cap M^c\,,
$$
where $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.
Also
$$
f^{-1} U = (f|_{M^c}^{-1}U) \cup ((f^{-1} U) \cap M)\,.
$$
Hence $f^{-1} U$ is the union of two measurable sets and thus measurable.